# How to remove link from div and add it to another div through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove the `<a>` from `list-container` to `selected container` on `click`. how to do that with jQuery.

```
<div class="list-container">
    <a class="list-item" data-type="community" href="javascript:{}">Community Tower 2<span class="icon icon-add"></span></a>
    <a class="list-item" data-type="community" href="javascript:{}">Community Tower 3<span class="icon icon-add"></span></a>
</div>

<div class="selected-container">
    <a class="list-item" href="javascript:{}">U-Bora Tower (Property) <span class="icon icon-remove"></span></a>
    <a class="list-item" href="javascript:{}">Business Bay (Community) <span class="icon icon-remove"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Show some code you have tried?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var target = $('.selected-container');
$('.list-container > a').click(function() {
    target.append($(this));
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/9cPQ5/)

Comment: You forgot to remove it from the original container.

Comment: @ATaylor No need to. `.append()` will not clone it. I will move it. Check the demo.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Because it changes the parent of the element. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Click function, write this code.

```
$(".selected-container").append($(".list-container").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".list-container a").click(function() {   
 $(this).prependTo('.selected-container');
});
```

my [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/b6FXM/)